# Xcode 5 iPhone app; all my '[' and ']' match, but "parse expected ']' " still comes up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, parsing, xcode5

i'm new and learning from a tutorial, i've coded in *python* before so i have mercilessly hunted for the additional '**]**' it claims it needs… and even when i put it in it then says, it's unexpected and want to delete it, leading back to the original problem. it says it expects a '**]**' on the line "**- (void)createOrOpenDB**" this is the view controller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *ArrayOfPowders;
    sqlite3  *powderDB;
    NSString *dbPathSring;

}

- (IBAction)AddPowderButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)DeletePowderButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)ShowAllButton:(id)sender;



@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ArrayOfPowders = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [[self mytableview]setDelegate:self];
    [[self mytableview]setDataSource:self];
    [self createOrOpenDB];
}

- (void)createOrOpenDB

{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    dbPathSring = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"powders.db"];

    char *error;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathSring]) {
        const char *dbpath = [dbPathSring UTF8String];

        // create db here
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &powderDB)==SQLITE_OK){
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS POWDERS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, POWDERNAME TEXT, RALCODE INTEGER, FINISH TEXT)";
            sqlite3_exec(powderDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error);
            sqlite3_close(powderDB);

        }
    }
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [ArrayOfPowders count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!Cell){
        Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        powder *apowder = [ArrayOfPowders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        Cell.textLabel.text = apowder.name;
        Cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",apowder.RAL];

        return Cell;

    }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didRecieveMemoryWarning];

}

    - (IBAction)addpowderbutton:(id)sender
    {

        if (sqlite3_open([dbPathSring UTF8String], &powderDB)==SQLITE_OK){
            NSString *inserStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO POWDERS(NAME,RAL) values ('%s' '%d')",[self.nameField.text UTF8String],[self.RAlField.text intValue]];

            const char *insert_stmt = [inserstmt UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_exec(powderDB, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"powder added");

                powder *powder = [[powder alloc]init];

                [powder setname:self.namefield.text];
                [powder setRALcode:[self.RALfield.text intValue]];

                [ArrayOfPowders addObject:powder];
            }
            sqlite3_close(powderDB);

        }
    }


}

- (IBAction)deletepowderbutton:(id)sender {

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;


}

- (IBAction)showallpowdersbutton:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)AddPowderButton:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)DeletePowderButton:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)ShowAllButton:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

viewcontroller.h is;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "powder.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *namefield;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *RALfield;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mytableview;
// items on main storyboard are give properties here


@end
```

Comment: Convention says that `ArrayOfPowders` should be `arrayOfPowders` that is only convention not a requirement.

Comment: Difference between following naming convention and not following is time spent on understanding what code author meant. `_arrayOfPowders` is quickly understood to be an ivar, and with ArrayOfPowders you have to spend time guessing: ivar? static variable? class?

Comment: The fact it is a capital `A` would say to be if I saw this in some code it is a class (I know it's not here) as classes should start with capital letters any variable whether static or ivar should start with lower case or in ivars case these days a `_`. This is way you should be staying to convention to create less confusion in your code. What would you do if you had `[ArrayOfPowders addObject:...];` this would seem to a developer that `ArrayOfPowders` is calling a class method and not an instance method, creates instant confusion.

Comment: just added the rest of the code, up to where the '}' gets put in as people keep on suggesting, but i'm wondering why it's expecting a ']'

Comment: Is this all the code as I have copied and pasted and not got that error. Also whats in .h

Comment: Can you add the complete file?

Comment: added the rest of view controller.m thats literally all of it, and also added view controller.h as requested

Comment: @Popeye: By convention, constants also start with a capital, as do enums and their options.

Comment: has anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 2):

On the method `createOrOpenDB` you are missing a closing `}` all you need to do is add it at the end like below (As long as this isn't a typo on the copying over to here)

```
- (void)createOrOpenDB 
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    dbPathSring = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"powders.db"];
}
```

**UPDATE**

Just because of how you have named `ArrayOfPowders` we can tell you aren't familiar with coding conventions so I am going to include [Apples Programming with Objective-c conventions documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) that I would recommend you have a read of as it will provide a better understanding of when to use uppercase and lowercase, method names, variable names etc

Answer (score 0):

Change your this code with

```
- (void)createOrOpenDB
  {
     NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
     dbPathSring = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"powders.db"];
```

to

```
- (void)createOrOpenDB
  {
     NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
     dbPathSring = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"powders.db"];
  }
```

As you forgot to close the function with "**}**"